# How to get JSON object in javascript from servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I am having one servlet class which is returning jsonobject using below code to the html page.

```
request.setAttribute("data", fullobj);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/poc2.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

How to get the object `fullobj` in my html page where javascript code is written?

Comment: You may use `cookie` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method if you make this as a JSP page, poc2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
${data}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I have taken poc2.jsp only. In that javascript code is written. There I am trying to get above fullobj using below code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now I have taken poc2.jsp only. In that javascript code is written. There I am trying to get above fullobj using below code. function access(){<% JSONObject obj= (JSONObject) request.getAttribute("data");String str=""+obj.toString(); //trying to convert fullobj into string
  System.out.println("string is"+str);
  %>var s=<%=str%>; //trying to assign that string to the javascript variable .
   alert(s);}        //here in alert fullobj is retuned in the form of JSON object instead of string . How to get JSON object in string and assign it to javascript variable var??

Comment: Also by following above solution , I am getting value of data in the form of JSON object not the string . Can I convert it from object to string and then assign it to the javascript variable ?

Comment: Could you post your json object ?  If you want a specific value from json object you can use getString method like this . If your json object is like this 
"data":
        {
            "result": "success",
            "code": "0"
            
        }
use obj.getString("result")

Comment: Thanks , for me  var prod = <%= request.getAttribute("data") %>; worked  where I am iterating the prod variable .